# How to create chrome profile desktop shortcut that will not open in new chrome window?

Tags: google-chrome

Recent versions of Google Chrome have a handy "profiles" feature. While creating a new profile, it's possible to set "create desktop shortcut" and a desktop shortcut will be created. Clicking on such shortcut will open a new Chrome window with the specified profile.

For some work patterns I need to switch between many profiles. The problem is that even when a profile is *already in use*, a new window appears when I click the shortcut.

Is it possible to somehow modify the shortcut so it won't open a *new* profile window, but focus the *existing* window instead if it's already opened?

Comment: so you actually want to use several chrome profiles in one chrome window? Or is the problem that even when a profile is already open, a new window appears when you click the shortcut?

Comment: @user99572isfine Updated question to improve accuracy. The problem is that if profile/app is already open, chrome opens second window. For lots of websites and apps it's meaningless to have 2 windows with them.

Comment: Your OS ? Possible in linux

Comment: Just forget about the desktop and pin the shortcut to the taskbar

Comment: This is by design. The windows of one profile are grouped into one. This is indicated by the profile label indicator on the top right. Use `{alt}`-`{tab}` to switch between windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Recent versions of Chrome have a handy "profiles" feature. While creting a new profile, it's possible to set "create desktop shortcut" and a desktop shortcut will be created. Clicking on such shortcut will open a new Chrome window with the specified profile.

Using *any* shortcut to run Chrome will launch a new window. Even if you have *no profiles*, running Chrome from a shortcut will launch a new instance with a new window.

> Such "open new or focus existing" behavior is very common among desktop rograms, but i can't find how to do this trick with Chrome desktop shortcuts. :(

The only way that Chrome will open a tab in an existing window is if you open a bookmark or `.html` file, but there is no practical way to control which profile those can be opened with because the handler is in Windows which only allows for a single handler. (I’ve come up with a system to support this, but it’s beyond the scope of this question.)

> For some work patterns I need to switch between many profiles. The problem is that even when a profile is *already in use*, a new window appears when I click the shortcut.

If the profile is already open, then why are you clicking the shortcut to open Chrome with the profile? If you want a new tab in that profile, then you can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in the appropriate window.

If your goal is simply to switch to the appropriate window (assuming you have so many different Chrome profiles that switching to the right one is difficult, even if you assign them different icons), then there’s no simple way to do that. Could try posting a [feature-request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) to support it.

> Is it possible to somehow modify the shortcut so it won't open a new profile window, but focus the existing window instead if it's already opened?

The closest you can currently get is to append `about:blank` to the end of the shortcut. It will switch to the specified profile and create a blank page, but you can easily close that.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome profile shortcuts]

Answer (score 2):

Eventhough you're offering a 100 bounty on this question. The fact still is that you can't do this. The functionality isn't there in chrome at the moment.

Comment: It's an acceptable answer. I need either a trusted answer that such thing is impossible or some flag/trick that will do a task.

Comment: There might not be any authoritative answer on this. Chromium dev forums maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Google Chrom version 40.0.2214.93m.

They easiest way how to make the shortcut directly to your Google profile is: Menu/Setting/
Then "edit profile" - sorry, my version is in Czech :-), so I'm not sure about the English view. Anyway that is the panel where you can choose the profile picture. And under all the pictures you have a choise "add a shorcut to the desktop". Jan

Comment: But clicking on such icon opens new browser window instead of focusing existing one, that's the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I could not find a solution to my problem, which is opening a shortcut in a new window without opening the web address AND a new tab.

But I have the solution for you people who want to open a shortcut in existing browser window.

Under Shortcut -> Target

After Default" simply put in the web address.

Example:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory=Default https://www.netflix.com

This will open the link in an existing browser window.